# If $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$ then $subst(\Sigma,s)\vdash subst(\varphi,s)$ for every $\varphi$.

Tags: logic

I trying to prove this:

> For a set of verses $\Sigma$ and a function $s:Var \to WFF$ let us define
>
> $$
> subst(\Sigma,s) = \left\{subst(\alpha,s) \mid \alpha\in\Sigma \right\} \;.
> $$
>   Prove that if $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$ then $subst(\Sigma,s)\vdash subst(\varphi,s)$ for every $\varphi$.

I started from the basic:
If $\varphi\in\Sigma$ then $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$, and by definiton of $subst$, we have $subst(\varphi,s) \in subst(\Sigma,s)$, and then $subst(\Sigma,s)\vdash subst(\varphi,s)$.

Now, I am trying to find the next untrivial movement to prove that $\Sigma\vdash\varphi$ for every $\varphi$, but I cannot see it.

Comment: This notation and terminology is unfamiliar to myself.  What is meant by a _verse_?  What is $\mathrm{substr}$ supposed to represent?  substitution?  Given a _verse_ $\alpha$, how is $\mathrm{substr} ( \alpha , s )$ defined?

Comment: the defenition of subst: for $i\in N$ subst($p_i$,s)=s($p_i$). for $\alpha,\beta\in WFF$ subst($(\neg\alpha)$,s)=$(\neg subst(\alpha,s))$ and $subst((\alpha\circ\beta),s)=(subst(\alpha,s)\circ subst(\beta,s))$

Comment: While $\circ\in${$\vee,\wedge,\rightarrow$}. And subst(O,s)=O , if $O\in{T,F}$.

Answer (score 1):

Which deducibility relation (expressed by '$\vdash$') is in question here? After all, we can easily concoct deviant deducibility relations which don't respect substitution. So it matters crucially which deduction system you are working with.

To show that a particular deducibility relation respects substitution, you'll need therefore to look at the definition of that relation. If what is in question is deducibility in e.g. a given system of first-order logic, then how the proof goes it will depend on how that system is presented. E.g. is it an old-fashioned axiomatic system with a built-in substitution rule?

Suppose it is a natural deduction system. Then the individual rules $R$ are usually presented in such a way that if you can readily check that if $\varphi$ follows immediately from assumptions $\Sigma$ by the rule $R$, then $subst(\varphi,s)$
follows from $subst(\Sigma,s)$. And then you can argue by induction on the size of proofs that if $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ then $subst(\Sigma,s)\vdash subst(\varphi,s)$.

But the details must depend on the particular deduction system you are working with. You can't argue entirely in the abstract.

Comment: So you saying that the induction must be on the size of the proof? I am working with the natural deduction system.

Comment: @MichaelCohen Yes, I guess so!

Comment: Can you show me you induction move? i have a problem to define it correctly.